# HomePage after login.(different domains)

Tags: javascript, java, node.js, reactjs

When user clicks on back button after user logs in, the user should stay in the home page instead of going back and seeing loginPage.

The loginPage(which has a different domain from the HomePage), can I control the behaviour from the UI(react) ? or is this issue must be address in server side??

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can control it from the frontend although this would only be for UI/UX purposes since an attacker could easily disable the javascript that makes it work.

Since you said you're using React, here's how I would do it:

```
// Login.js

import React, {useEffect} from "react";

const Login = () => {
  const checkAuth = () => true; // check auth with your own logic

  useEffect(() => {
    if(checkAuth()) {
      console.log(true);
    }

    else {
      window.location = "https://myapp.com/home"
    }
  }, [])

  return (
    <div>Only shown if logged in</div>
  )
}

export default Login;
```